# Google VR SDK: Right cam lighting problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

Left cam is rendering it right while the right cam seems to be missing something. It's a fresh project with GVR-SDK imported, I created a sphere and ran it. I thought default material is causing problems, but that doesn't seem to be the problem; Even with different colors and rendering mode, it remains the same!

[image]

How do I correct this?

Comment: doesn't work with the default cube too!

Comment: should I use VR Specific shaders?